# Assigning a weighted value to a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a spreadsheet in Excel.  Column A is student's name. Column B is a placement test score.  Column C is a benchmark score. Column D is an effort score. Column E is for a TOTAL score.   How do I assign column B a weight of 20%, column C a weight of 50%, and column D a weight of 30% to give me a total for column E?

Answer (score 4):

The formula for E should be

> =(B1*.2) + (C1 *.5) + (D1 *.3)

Parens may not be needed but should work.